# Turning a div and its children into a modal/popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to have the div and its children show in modal/popup while still remaining in their original DOM positions. I am unable to move the div, or its contents, around in the DOM because of some javascript that requires extensive tree traversal when a checkbox is clicked inside of the parent div. We are using bootstrap modals in the project, so a solution that allows me to use a modal would be ideal.

*I know I can achieve this with custom CSS, but I would like to know if there is a cleaner way (Example: `$('div').modal('show')`), rather than me faking a modal/popup

```
<!--datagrid-fields is what I am trying it make into a modal/popup-->
<!--getSelect() just returns an HTML checkbox list-->

    <li id="gridCheckboxesEntryInfo" class="threeColumns">
        <input type="checkbox" onClick="selectAllFields(this)"> Select All<br>
        <a class="btn btn-primary reorderFields" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reorderModal">Reorder Fields</a>
        <a class="btn btn-success selectFields">Select Fields</a>
        <div style="display:inline-block;margin-left: 5%;"><h3 style="display:inline-block;font-size: 18px">Scroll Down to View Fields</h3><div class="arrow bounce"><a class="arrow bounce"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-2x"></i></a></div></div>
        <div id="datagrid-fields">
            <?=getSelect($fieldsbysetwithwidget, $fieldsindb, 'checkboxes');?>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clone a div before making a popup of it.

```
$('#datagrid-fields').clone().modal('show')
```

Note, you need to clean up some attributes like `id` if it is used somewhere else. In addition you have to remove modal div on close:

```
$cloned.on('hidden.bs.modal', function () { $cloned.remove() });
```

You probably need to wrap cloned contents with modal wrapping div like

```
$cloned.wrap('<div class="modal ..."></div>');
```

So the final version is

```
var $cloned = $('#datagrid-fields').clone();
$cloned.wrap('<div class="modal ..."></div>');

var $modal = $cloned.parent();
$modal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function () { $modal.remove() });
$modal.modal('show');
```